# React Page not rendering properly in FireFox alone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

The UI on hover/click is changing the page to a blank. I have worked with React before and this has never happened. The oddest part is that this issue is occurring only in the FireFox browser. While the page seems to render correctly every time, the page seems to distort sometimes.

The page was created using create-react-app and the components I used are from reactstrap and MUI.

The page has a tabs component imported from reactstrap within which the MUI table has been placed.
An example of the code which I have used can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-moon-gp4l6?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js

The blur is happening when any part of the MUI component is being clicked.

There are no errors showing up in the console. Each of the individual components also seem to be working just as expected.

Code looks something like this:

```
 <Nav tabs>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
            onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); window.location.reload()}}
          >
            Tab 1
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
            onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}
          >
            Tab 2
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
  </Nav>
  <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
        <TabPane tabId="1">
          <MUITable 1/>
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tabId="2">
          <MUITable 2/>
        </TabPane>
  </TabContent>
```

I didn't want to make any changes in the code as it seems to affect the functionality in other browsers.

Some research showed me that there were some issues with MUI table and firefox a few years ago, but it had been fixed. There doesn't seem to any obvious indications to why this was happening.

The table looks normal, just as expected(Same as in codesandbox) before the user interacts with the page.

But after interacting with the page, this happens:
[image: after interaction with the page]

Basically it blanks out on hover or click.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code for example as a jsfiddle? Otherwise it might be a little difficult to help.

Comment: You can find the code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-moon-gp4l6?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js

Comment: Update: This issue seems to be intermittent.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the described behaviour. At a first glance I suspect the line 29 `window.location.reload();` in `Tabs/Tabs.js` might be responsible.
https://codesandbox.io/s/still-bash-wb1i3?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, this helped me solve the issue that I was facing with the page blanking out while switching between tabs. I am still facing issues with the styling blanking out upon any page interaction whatsoever.